# casting a list<baseclass> to a list<derivedclass>

Tags: c#, .net, casting, generic-list

I have a number of classes all inheriting from a base class - which in fact is simply a wrapper for an interface to allow serialisation thus:

```
public abstract class VoucherRuleBase : IRule{
    public abstract bool Save(int nodeID);
}

public class ActiveDateRule : VoucherRuleBase{
   public DateTime ActiveDateRuleProperty{get;set;}
  ...etc
}
```

I then have a `List<VoucherRuleBase>` which contains a number of `ActiveDateRule` objects, or a number of the other derived classes. the list is always full of the same types, ie. all ActiveDateRules or one of the other derived classes.

I need to cast/convert the List to a List, as I am trying to bind the list to a grid, but as the grid only sees the base class it cant find any of the properties. at runtime .NET is aware of the 'real' types, just at compile time I cannot cast it over. is this because it simply isn't possible - without having some constructor on each of the derived classes to do the conversion?

I have searched on here and there are indeed other questions similar to this, but I am not having any luck with those solutions..

any help much appreciated as ever.. 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `myList.Cast<BaseClass>`?

Comment: apologies it was passing the list to a control which hadnt recompiled and was set to the base class type.. doh!
both : .OfType<ActiveDateRule>() and .Cast<ActiveDateRule>() worked..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `as`.

```
List<VoucherRuleBase> voucherRules = new List<VoucherRuleBase>();
var activeDateRules = voucherRules.Select(x => x as ActiveDateRule);
```

You aren't doing implicit casts this way and you can filter out ***bad*** objects by using `Where` and filtering types that aren't `null`.

```
var activeDateRules = voucherRules.Select(x => x as ActiveDateRule).Where(x => x != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here baseClasses is a list of your base class.
And DerivedClass1 is your derieved class.

```
var derivedClasses = baseClasses.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(DerivedClass1)).ToList();
```